# Exact value of limit

Tags: limits

Find the exact value of

$ \lim_{x\to  \infty }  (1+ \frac {1}{2x} - \frac {15}{16x^2})^{6x}$.

Feel tempted to reduce $(1+ \frac {1}{2x} - \frac {15}{16x^2})$ to 1 as $x$ appoaches infinity, but a quick check on the GC yields the final answer as $e^3$.

I'm not sure how to arrive there.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1{2x})^{2x}=e$

Comment: I have modified my answer to contain the full steps of working, but try yourself from the hint I gave first before reading the answer :)

Comment: That helped great, thanks both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to limits, you have to be very careful about steps like you mentioned, reducing the inside to ${1}$ - because what you really have is a ${1^{\infty}}$ situation, which is an indeterminate form.

Hint: rewrite the limit as ${e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{15}{16x^2}\right)^{6x}\right)}}$. If you want to see the full answer, continue reading.

This can be simplified to ${e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}6xln\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{15}{16x^2}\right)}}$. Now since ${e^x}$ is continuous, we can simply find the limit of ${\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}6x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{15}{6x^2}\right)}$ and raise e to this power. This is,

$${\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{15}{6x^2}\right)}{\frac{1}{6x}}}$$

And now this is a ${\frac{0}{0}}$ situation in the limit, we can use the infamous L'hopital's rule. Differentiating the top and bottom gives some ugly expression:

$${\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{10-x}{x(2x^2+x-5)}}{\frac{-1}{6x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{6x(10-x)}{2x^2+x-5}=3}$$

(if you are confused why this limit is $3$, let me know in the comments and I will explain). And hence the overall limit is ${e}$ to this power, which is ${e^3}$. As expected