# How to prove the following limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)^{6n}=e^3$$

Let $y = \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)^{6n}$, so $\ln y = 6n \ln\left(1+\frac{8n-15}{16n^2}\right)$.

Using the standard series for $\ln (1+x)$, I got $$\ln y = 6n\left(\frac{8n-15}{16n^2}-\frac{\left(\frac{8n-15}{16n^2}\right)^{2}}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{8n-15}{16n^2}\right)^{3}}{3}+...\right)$$

Applying l'Hopital rule on $6n(-\frac{(\frac{8n-15}{16n^2})^{2}}{2})$ (the second term), I get $\frac{2304}{6144n}$ which tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. *This follows for the 3rd, 4th and subsequent $n$th terms which all tends to $0$.* **How to then prove the statement in italics such that I can continue with the following steps?**

$$\ln y = 6n\left(\frac{8n-15}{16n^2}\right) \to 3$$ (Applying l'Hopital rule)

Which gives $\lim_{n \to +\infty}y=e^3$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exact value of limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720628/exact-value-of-limit) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%2B%5Cinfty%7D(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2n%7D-%5Cfrac%7B15%7D%7B16n%5E2%7D)%5E%7B6n%7D%3De%5E3%24&p=1).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: You evaluate or calculate limits, you do not "prove" them.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The target duplicate is also closed, so we can't add any other answer with alternative discussion. How do we handle these cases?

Comment: We can use that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)^{6n}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)^{\frac 1{\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}}}\right]^{6n\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)}$$ with $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right)^{\frac 1{\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}}} \to e$$ and $$6n\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{15}{16n^2}\right) \to 3$$

Comment: @user I'm not sure offhand how to best handle, in general, the cases where the target duplicate question is also closed, but where you wish to answer with an alternative discussion. Several possibilities include that one can do as you did (i.e., provide an "answer" in a comment), try to reopen the current or duplicate question, find another duplicate (but open) question to post an answer to, and post a new question (with it referring to this question) that includes your alternative discussion in either the question itself or in a self-answer. Do you have any additional suggestions?